# Google maps - how to add marker without layout refresh

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web, refresh, marker

Have problem with marker adding.

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });

    // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
    marker.setMap(map);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/73ogq84a/

Simple example, each seconds I put marker, page not reloading, but reloading some layout and we see effect of map reload.

It is possible to do that put marker smoothly.

But on this page http://www.flightradar24.com/simple_index.php all working fine, planes are flying and no effect of map reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the marker and map global.  Don't recreate the map every time, just move the marker.

```
var map, marker, myLatlng;

setInterval(function () {
    if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "Hello World!"
        });

        // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
        marker.setMap(map);
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
    }

}, 5000);
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73ogq84a/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Provide map property when you create marker:

```
function placeMarker(location) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location, 
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```